# Navigate from tableViewcell to new tableview to new view, Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am working with a Xcode project where I have two tableviews and one ordinary view. 
The first tableview have 9 different cells and when you click one of theese I want to navigate to the second tableview and fill it with contents from a different array depending on which cell you clicked on in the first tableview.

After that I want to be able to click on a cell in the second tableview and from there navigate to a view controller that shows different pictures and text in textfields depending on which cell i clicked there.

I don't know if I'm gonna use prepare for segue or something else.

I am stuck and in a hurry so I would be very grateful for help.

This is the code I have for the first tableView:

```
#import "ValjKategoriViewController.h"
#import "ValjKupongViewController.h"
#import "Kupong.h"

@interface ValjKategoriViewController ()

@end

@implementation ValjKategoriViewController

@synthesize kategoriArray;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Alla aktuella kuponger",@"Restauranger & Cafeer",@"Dagens lunch",@"Friskvård & Hälsa", @"Dagligvaror", @"Frisörer",@"Shopping",@"Bil & Motor",@"Upplevelser & Nöje",nil];
    self.kategoriArray = array;
    self.title = @"Kategori";
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [kategoriArray count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SimpleTableIdentifier"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"SimpleTableIdentifier"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [kategoriArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}
```

Comment: If you are using a storyboard, then segues and `prepareForSegue` is certainly the simplest path.  If you look at the `UIStoryboardSegue` documentation, Apple lists five downloadable sample applications related to it.

Comment: or lesson 10 here https://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/developing-apps-for-ios-sd/id395631522

Comment: How am I going to do in the storyboard?